# sql datatable in a jtable

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

i m a debutant on programming in java netbeans so i m traying to display a Data table in a jFrame table it doesn't work so here the code :

```
 package presentation;
    import DAO.signalisation_freelancerDAO;
    import technique.myconnexion;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.sql.*;
    import DAO.FreelancerDAO;
    import ENTITE.Freelancer;
    import ENTITE.signalisation_freelancer;
    import java.util.*;
    import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;



    public class ListFreelancerSingalise1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    Connection url=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;
    PreparedStatment pst=null;


    public ListFreelancerSingalise1() {
    initComponents();
    url=myconnexion.myConnection;
    Update_table();
    }
    private void Update_table()
    {
    try{
    String sql="select * from signalisation_freelancer";
    pst=(PreparedStatment) url.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs=pst.executeQuery();
    jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    }

    catch(Exception e ){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    }




    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

    jRadioButtonMenuItem1 = new javax.swing.JRadioButtonMenuItem();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();

    jRadioButtonMenuItem1.setSelected(true);
    jRadioButtonMenuItem1.setText("jRadioButtonMenuItem1");

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setText("Liste des freelancer signalisé");

    jButton1.setText("Activer");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
    }
    });

    jButton2.setText("Supprimer");
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
    }
    });

    jButton3.setText("recherche");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new               
    javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                  jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(50, 50, 50)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 89, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addContainerGap(45, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jButton3)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jButton2)
            .addGap(8, 8, 8))
    );

    jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null}
        },
        new String [] {
            "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
        }
    ));
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(157, 157, 157)
                    .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(51, 51, 51)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 452, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(193, 193, 193)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)))
            .addContainerGap(90, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(20, 20, 20)
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 91, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 18, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

}                                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ListFreelancerSingalise1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ListFreelancerSingalise1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ListFreelancerSingalise1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ListFreelancerSingalise1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new ListFreelancerSingalise1().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JRadioButtonMenuItem jRadioButtonMenuItem1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

and this is the connection class java:

```
package technique;

/**
 *
 * @author ASUS
 */
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author ASUS
 */
public class myconnexion {
     String login="root";
     String pwd="";
    String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/freelance";
    public static  Connection myConnection;

public myconnexion() 
{
         try {
                          myConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(url , login, pwd);


             System.out.println("connexion ok ");
         } catch (SQLException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(myconnexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }

}
public static Connection getinstance()
{
    if(myConnection==null)

      {             
         myConnection=(Connection) new myconnexion();

      }
      return myConnection;

}
}
```

Here the result when i compile in the intrface jFrame, the jtable is empty so any help about that  :( :

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you get data from your database, I think it should show up in your Swing table. Consider adding some println statements to check if you receive the data from the database that you expect. For updating and removing data with the buttons, you need to add code to the jButton[1|2]ActionPerformed methods. For example:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    updateTable();
}

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.getEmptyTableModel());
}
```

To make your application work for me without a database, I've changed the `updateTable` method (note the else):

```
private void updateTable() {
    try {
        if (url != null) {
            final String sql = "select * from signalisation_freelancer";
            pst = url.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
        } else
            jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.getTestTableModel());
    } catch (final SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

It saves time if you include references to external libraries you use. I had some difficulty finding the `DbUtils` class that you use. After some searching I came across a version of it on http://technojeeves.com/index.php/9-freebies/22-resultset-to-tablemodel. Later I also saw it on http://sourceforge.net/p/finalangelsanddemons/code/HEAD/tree/AngelsAndDemon_1_1/src/rs2xml.jar.

This is the version from TechnoJeeves that I modified and extended a bit (added some test methods):

```
package com.stackoverflow.q28649773;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

/**
 * Originally from http://technojeeves.com/index.php/9-freebies/22-resultset-to-tablemodel.
 */
public class DbUtils {
    /**
     * Convert a database result set to a Swing table model.
     *
     * @param resultSet the input database result set.
     * @return the Swing table model that has been constructed.
     */
    public static TableModel resultSetToTableModel(final ResultSet resultSet) {
        TableModel result = null;

        try {
            final ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
            final int numberOfColumns = metaData.getColumnCount();

            // Get the column names.
            final List<String> columnNames = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= numberOfColumns; columnIndex++)
                columnNames.add(metaData.getColumnLabel(columnIndex));

            // Get all rows with data.
            final List<List<Object>> data = new ArrayList<>();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                final List<Object> newRow = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= numberOfColumns; columnIndex++) {
                    System.out.println(resultSet.getObject(columnIndex));
                    newRow.add(resultSet.getObject(columnIndex));
                }

                data.add(newRow);
            }

            result = new DefaultTableModel(new Vector<>(data), new Vector<>(columnNames));
        } catch (final SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static TableModel getTestTableModel() {
        final String[] columnNames = {"A", "B", "C"};
        final Object[][] data = {{"1", "2", "3"}, {"i", "ii", "iii"}};
        return new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
    }

    public static TableModel getEmptyTableModel() {
        final String[] columnNames = {"A", "B", "C"};
        final Object[][] data = {};
        return new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
    }
}
```

Finally some small suggestions:

- consider following Java naming conventions, for example: method `updateTable` (instead of `Update_table`) and class
  `MyConnexion` (instead of `myconnexion`).
- take a look at the spelling of `PreparedStatment`; should it be `PreparedStatement`?

Good luck with your project!